# Can we know the tension of the string that is connected to a pully?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, string

[image]
If the pulley have mass, I learned that T1 and T2 isn't same. then what about the circled part of the string? can we calculate the tension with given T1 and T2?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in between $T_1$ and $T_2$ -- but exactly what depends on details about how the friction between the string and the pulley varies, how the string stretches under tension and the pulley deforms while being accelerated by the string ... All of these are things that cannot be deduced from an idealized picture such as this.

In one extreme, if the pulley is a gear and the string is a chain whose links are naturally slightly longer than the tooth spacing of the gear, the string tension at your yellow circle may approach *zero*, even if both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are higher. You probably won't call that a "string", but it's not easy to define a crisp distinction between the two cases.

Comment: then why can we ignore the circled part when we calculate the torque of the pulley?

Comment: @YunHoo: Can we? Who says that? Are they right? Do they assume that the string is massless? Which torque?

Comment: Yes, the string was massless. I mean the torque of the pulley.

Comment: Is there a difference if the string is massless?